# Can't Connect to Wifi adhoc network created in windows 7 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

I have Two laptops. One is running on Windows 7 and connected to internet though wire and other is running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have Created a wifi adhoc network in windows 7 machine and shared the internet connection..
From any other windows machine I can connect to the wifi and connect to internet But
when I am trying to connect through the Ubuntu machine after it takes few moments and gets failed to connect.. Please Help me..
This the output of some commands

**dmesg**

```
[14804.471075] wlan0: Selected IBSS BSSID f6:39:0c:35:16:74 based on configured SSID
[14804.494144] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[14804.494253] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: Beacon enabled: true
[14804.494266] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: IBSS joined: true (implement)
[14804.494337] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[14822.498047] wlan0: No active IBSS STAs - trying to scan for other IBSS networks with same SSID (merge)
[14822.498086] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: Beacon enabled: false
[14823.114160] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: Beacon enabled: true
[14850.120618] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: Beacon enabled: false
[14850.120635] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: IBSS joined: false (implement)
[14850.320247] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[14850.320260] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[14850.320406] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```